# micropython for statement syntax

Tags: micropython

Recently came upon the following syntax that includes elements for which I have been unable to find a reference:

```
for(auto i = 0u; i < (reference to an object element here) ; i++)
```

To what does "auto" refer?  What is the "u" modifying the initial index?

Alternatively, where can I find documentation relating to these questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Plainly, that's not micropython code. Are you sure it's not C++?

Comment: Well, actually, no, I'm not sure that it is not C++.

Comment: In that case it's extremely likely that it is C++. In C++, the [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) keyword serves as a placeholder for type for type inference. In this case, the type of `i` is being inferred from the type of `0u`, with is an [`unsigned int` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). Hence, `i` is an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Brian, thank you for clearing this up for me!